# Objective-C - footer for my app

Tags: ios, footer

I'm trying to make a footer for my app. when I say footer I mean this: http://gyazo.com/8987010f51f420bd61cde1b6e1b70087

What is the name of the component (the black one)?

Sincerely,
Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a [UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).